# How to count only active users as referred users?

Tags: wordpress

I am using self-hosted WordPress. And, I need a refer system for my site. It's a membership type site.
Where I offer refer code to some specific members. So, they can refer others.
And, when someone sign ups through their refer link, they will get a point.
For referral code, I am using WP Referral Code (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-referral-code/).
And, for membership I am using Ultimate Member Plugin!
But the issue is, WP Referral Code is counting registrations when someone hit the sign up button!
Even If I reject he membership via Ultimate Plugin, its still being counted!
How can i count only valid signups which are active right now? Not all sign ups, just manually approved sign ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update WP Referral Code to new version and paste this in your functions.php file

```php
add_filter( 'wp_referral_code_validate_submission', function ($result){
    return false;
}, 1, 1);

add_action( 'wp_referral_code_before_refer_submitted', function ( $new_user_id, $referrer_user_id){
    update_user_meta( $new_user_id, 'shalior_referrer_id', $referrer_user_id);
}  , 10 , 2);


add_action( 'um_after_user_is_approved', 'shalior_um_after_user_is_approved', 10, 1 );
function shalior_um_after_user_is_approved( $user_id ) {
    $referrer_user_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'shalior_referrer_id', true);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wrc_referrer_id', $referrer_user_id );

    wp_referral_code_add_user_to_referrer_invite_list($user_id , $referrer_user_id);
}
```